# Problems with #Cmakedefine and Set

Tags: cmake

I am trying to add some directory finding abilities to a CMake script with

```
if(PCRE_FOUND)
    if(IS_DIRECTORY "${PCRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}pcre")
        set( HAVE_PCREINCDIR 1)
    endif(IS_DIRECTORY "${PCRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}pcre")
endif(PCRE_FOUND)
```

And in a config.h file:

```
#cmakedefine PCRE_SUPPORT
#cmakedefine HAVE_PCREINCDIR
```

However `HAVE_PCREINCDIR` never gets set, eve though that dir DOES exist

And `message("${PCRE_INCLUDE_DIRS}pcre")` outputs: `C:\pcre\include\pcre`

Comment: Is `HAVE_PCREINCDIR` variable is actually set? (You may add `message()` call to inner `if` clause). Show also how(and where) you execute `configure_file`, and what is resulted file's content.

Comment: I have, as stated, added message in there before, and got output. showing that bit of code IS reached`#define PCRE_SUPPORT
/* #undef HAVE_PCREINCDIR */`   ... and i now realise what is wrong

Comment: When debugging, it is better to perform *direct* checks: `if(IS_DIRECTORY)` may return false for various reasons, but if `message()` in inner `if` clause is executed, then `set(HAVE_PCREINCDIR 1)` is **definitely** executed.

Comment: I did put a message in the inner class, As I state in my post below however your second guess was right, I had `configure_file` in the wrong place, the fact that cached options were being set correctly had confused me some.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out, I had put configure_file before this, and the reason it worked for options is of course, they were cached.

Moving configure_file as @Tsyvarev suggested corrected this.